# It seems that JDBCTemplate ignores SET CONSTRAINT ALL DEFERRED

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am having this Spring 4.0 service that copies tables from one schema to another. I am switching between Datasources programmatically by updating the Datasource in an abstract class from which all DAOs inherit.

```
public abstract class GenericDao implements SystemChangedListener {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GenericDao.class);

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;    
    /**
     * Initializing the bean with the definition data source through @Autowired
     * @param definitionDataSource as instance of @DataSource
     */

    @Autowired
    private void setDataSource(DataSource definitionDataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(definitionDataSource);
    }

    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(){
        return this.jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
```

Whenever I need to switch to anothe DataSource I call this method. It all works fine so far, except for the cases when I have a parent-child tables in a foreign key relationship with foreign key defined as deferrable. I get 'ORA-02292: integrity constraint - child record' found whenever the application tries to delete first the parent table.

This happens in a service by calling the methods like this:

```
logger.info("Switching to target system: " + repDTO.getSourceSystem());
systemService.switchSystem(targetSys);

logger.info("Cleaning up data in target table: " + repDTO.getTableToReplicate());
// deleting the data
managedTableService.cleanData(repDTO.getTableToReplicate());
logger.info("Importing data in target table: " + repDTO.getTableToReplicate());
// importing the data
managedTableService.importData(inserts);
```

Methods are executed in a transaction so when something goes wrong I return to the clean state. I also use Hibernate for collecting meta information about my tables, before copying them, but for this I use a different connection.

I tried to call SET CONSTRAINT ALL DEFERRED before the cleaning method, but it doesn't work. I even tried a batch update - SET CONSTRAINT ALL DEFERRED + DELETE FROM TABLE, still no success. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

PS. I use Oracle 11 as a DB. Here's my spring datasource configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/db.properties" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
            p:packagesToScan="de.telekom.cldb.admin"
            p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
            p:jpaPropertyMap-ref="jpaPropertyMap"
            p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateVendor" />

    <bean id="hibernateVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.dialect}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- system 'definition' data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${db.driver}"
          p:url="${db.url}"
          p:username="${db.username}"
          p:password="${db.password}" />
          <!-- 
          p:maxActive="${dbcp.maxActive}"
          p:maxIdle="${dbcp.maxIdle}"
          p:maxWait="${dbcp.maxWait}"/>
           -->

    <util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
        <entry key="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${db.dialect}"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.default_schema" value="${db.schema}"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob" value="true"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />        
    </util:map>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

For switching between DataSources progammatically I use org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

######## UPDATE

[Hibernate DEBUG log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B30Q8jSMJvU5WmZWdDdaVmtvME0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you post hibernate DEBUG level log generated while the process that you have mentioned.

Comment: ...and why you are deleting records from parent table first? According to best practice you should delete records first from child then from parent. Is there any specific need to delete records from parent first?

Comment: Oracle recommends the same, read more @ http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora02292.php

Comment: @user3813463, I don't think the resolution provided in link is recommended by oracle as this link is not official oracle document, the author of that article suggested the resolution. But anyways Thanks!!

Comment: @Amogh I will post the log tomorrow, cause I don't have the code with me. I am deleting the tables in no specific order, cause I have restrictions in time - to check which one is the parent will take to much time, because the database is huge and there are a lot of relationships.

Comment: @Amogh I've just uploaded the hibernate debug log.

Comment: OK, I think I've found out where my problem is - the transaction gets committed after deleting the parent table. Apparently the hibernate transaction doesn't handle the jdbc connections correctly and an autocommit is allowed to happen.

Comment: I've rewritten the whole method and packed all statments (DEFER CONSTRAINTS, DELETES and INSERTS) in a batchUpdate, using one JdbcTemplate connection only and I am still getting:

java.sql.BatchUpdateException ORA-02292: integrity constraint - child record found

Comment: ALTER SESSION SET CONSTRAINTS = DEFERRED; doesn't work either. Also setting it in BasicDataSource as connectionInitSqls doesn't work. (Tested with both ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc7.jar )

Comment: @al. okay, gone through log provided by you but didn't anything rather then `ORA-02292`, As I said it's clearly error of deleting parent record without deleting child reference. what about setting on-delete-cascade so that deletion on parent record will automatically delete child records?

Comment: @Amogh Thanks. Unfortunately I don't get to decide how the tables should be created. The database of the clients consists of a lot of tables, some of them pretty old but still in use.